# Next.JS 14 and Shadcn Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: next.js, shadcnui

Nextjs14 with Shadcn on a fresh project.
I dont know why im getting a hydration error.
Ive tried to apply asChild on Trigger,
nohydration on Trigger however both did not work out.
I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance ;)

```
'use client'


import {
    NavigationMenu,
    NavigationMenuContent,
    NavigationMenuItem,
    NavigationMenuList,
    NavigationMenuTrigger,
  } from "@/components/ui/navigation-menu"
  
export function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="flex justify-center mt-5">
      <img src="/logo.png" className="h-24 w-48 mr-5"/>
    <NavigationMenu>
      <NavigationMenuList>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger>
                Produkte
         </NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger >Direktabschluss</NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger >Leistungen</NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger >Unternehmen</NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger >Rechtliches</NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
      </NavigationMenuList>
    </NavigationMenu>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code where you actually using this component?

Answer (score 0):

I did not put the Component correctly in the layout

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).